# PHP : mcrypt & openssl producing different output

Tags: php, encryption, openssl

Hoping someone can shed some light on this.

I am updating some older code which uses the `mcrypt_generic` function, utilizing a DES-CBC cipher

When I update this code to use the `openssl_encrypt`, I get the same output, but with 8 bytes appended to the end of my encoded string.

Before

```
$this->_cipher = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_DES, '', MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,'');
mcrypt_generic_init($this->_cipher, $this->_key, $this->_iv) 
mcrypt_generic($this->_cipher, $text)
```

Before method output:

> 27049189e7e08db6

After

```
openssl_encrypt($text, "DES-CBC", $this->_key,  OPENSSL_RAW_DATA , $this->_iv);
```

After method output:

> 27049189e7e08db6d504d16516e1c567

Why is this happening, and what (other then a substring) can be done to prevent it?

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48800725/convert-mcrypt-generic-to-openssl-encrypt

Comment: I would look into the padding. Since openssl is a modern library it probably uses modern padding standards (like PKCS#7) and mcrypt could use an older technique (like zero padding). I don't know for sure but I had a similar problem and I think it was the padding that was different.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1829#section-1.3):

> 1.3.  Data Size
> The DES algorithm operates on blocks of eight octets. This often requires padding after the end of the unencrypted payload data.

It's possible that it's simply padding the input.

`mcrypt_encrypt()` seems to pad by 0 by default (based on code example in [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php)):

```
# creates a cipher text compatible with AES (Rijndael block size = 128)
# to keep the text confidential 
# only suitable for encoded input that never ends with value 00h
# (because of default zero padding)
$ciphertext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key,
$plaintext, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
```

which would explain the difference in length.

Answer (score 1):

So I manage to find a solution

```
openssl_encrypt($text, "DES-CBC", $this->_key,  OPENSSL_NO_PADDING, $this->_iv);
```

This mode,

> OPENSSL_NO_PADDING

seems to produce the output I was expecting

Comment: Weirdly, the PHP documentation doesn't mention this mode. Only "OPENSSL_RAW_DATA" & "OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING"